# Как удалить(убрать) QLayout из другого QLayuot

Tags: c++, qt

Есть Layout, который содержит другой под-Layout. В некий момент мне нужно этот под-Layout удалить, а новый добавить.

```
QVBoxLayout* mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout; //layout
QHBoxLayout* subLayout = new QHBoxLayout; //под-layout
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   subLayout->addWidget(new QPushButton(this)); //содержимое под-layout'a
mainLayout->addLayout(subLayout);
setLayout(mainLayout);
```

После этого необходимо subLayout и его содержимое убрать, а какой-то новый с другим содержимым добавить.

Как? `QLayout` предоставляет только `removeWidget`, и совсем никакого removeLayout, а просто `delete subLayout;` никакого здравого эффекта не дает.

Comment: Qt ещё живой? помню в детстве на нём писал, когда ещё Nokia была такая компания, телефоны производила.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [removeItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#removeItem), это как раз то, что Вам нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Следует всегда назначать родителя для виджета и лэйаутов:

```
QVBoxLayout* mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this); //layout
QHBoxLayout* subLayout = new QHBoxLayout(this); //под-layout
```

В этом случае `delete` должен работать.